# Exporting TDS projects into template is not working

Tags: tds

I need to add a new site in project layer of my helix based project. currently will be copying the existing dot net project present in project layer and manually updating the namespace references and config areas. Instead of doing such manual activities we found that the project can be exported to template and created as a new project including the namespace changes which it worked, but the problem here is we noticed the TDS projects along with its contents are not converted to template based project. Only dot net project can be able to be exported to templates. is there any approach to export tds project into template ? so that i can create one more new tds project with the same content present.